# Naive single output Q Network: how to combine state/action for input?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Most often in (deep) Q network implementations are made using DeepMind's approach of having the state as the network's input and the individual Q-values for each output [1].

My question is related is its naive construction, this is, having the state/action pair as input and the Q value as the output [1]: how would you combine the state (say, represented by a stack of images) with a given action, if order to feed the pair to the network?

[1] Naive (left) and optimised (right) q network architectures: https://www.nervanasys.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Screen-Shot-2015-12-21-at-11.27.12-AM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've eventually found one possible answer to this.

When approximating the Q-function with a network which accepts both the state and action as inputs, if we use a we use a convolutional network ending in a fully connected layer for example, then one option would to add the action as an additional input on this fully connected layer.